# Moving from one frame to another in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-instances, windowbuilder

I'm just making a small application on window builder and need some help with it. I've made 2 frames individually and I don't know how to specify the action of the button in such a way that when I click on the 'next' botton in the first frame, I want it to move to the second frame.

Here's the source code for each file.

first.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class first extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private final Action action = new SwingAction();
private final Action action_1 = new SwingAction();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                first frame = new first();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public first() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnNext.setAction(action_1);
    btnNext.setBounds(257, 228, 55, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNext);

    JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.setBounds(344, 228, 51, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnExit);

    JRadioButton rdbtnAdd = new JRadioButton("Add");
    rdbtnAdd.setBounds(27, 80, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnAdd);

    JRadioButton rdbtnDelete = new JRadioButton("Delete");
    rdbtnDelete.setBounds(27, 130, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnDelete);

    JRadioButton rdbtnEdit = new JRadioButton("Edit");
    rdbtnEdit.setBounds(27, 180, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnEdit);

    JLabel lblSelectAnOption = new JLabel("Select an Option");
    lblSelectAnOption.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    lblSelectAnOption.setBounds(27, 36, 121, 23);
    contentPane.add(lblSelectAnOption);
}
private class SwingAction extends AbstractAction {
    public SwingAction() {
        putValue(NAME, "Next");
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Some short description");
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new second_add();
    }
}
}
```

second.java

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import javax.swing.Action;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


    public class second_add extends JFrame {

        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JTextField txtTypeYourQuestion;
        private JTextField txtQuestionWeight;
        private JTextField txtEnter;
        private JTextField txtEnter_1;
        private JTextField txtValue;
        private JTextField txtValue_1;
        private final Action action = new SwingAction();

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        second_add frame = new second_add();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public second_add() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);

            txtTypeYourQuestion = new JTextField();
            txtTypeYourQuestion.setBounds(22, 11, 177, 20);
            txtTypeYourQuestion.setText("Type your Question Here");
            contentPane.add(txtTypeYourQuestion);
            txtTypeYourQuestion.setColumns(10);

            txtQuestionWeight = new JTextField();
            txtQuestionWeight.setBounds(209, 11, 86, 20);
            txtQuestionWeight.setText("Question weight");
            contentPane.add(txtQuestionWeight);
            txtQuestionWeight.setColumns(10);

            txtEnter = new JTextField();
            txtEnter.setBounds(22, 55, 86, 20);
            txtEnter.setText("Enter . . .");
            contentPane.add(txtEnter);
            txtEnter.setColumns(10);

            txtEnter_1 = new JTextField();
            txtEnter_1.setText("Enter . . . ");
            txtEnter_1.setBounds(22, 104, 86, 20);
            contentPane.add(txtEnter_1);
            txtEnter_1.setColumns(10);

            txtValue = new JTextField();
            txtValue.setText("Value . .");
            txtValue.setBounds(118, 55, 51, 20);
            contentPane.add(txtValue);
            txtValue.setColumns(10);

            txtValue_1 = new JTextField();
            txtValue_1.setText("Value . .");
            txtValue_1.setBounds(118, 104, 51, 20);
            contentPane.add(txtValue_1);
            txtValue_1.setColumns(10);

            JButton btnFinish = new JButton("Finish");
            btnFinish.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                }
            });
            btnFinish.setAction(action);
            btnFinish.setBounds(335, 228, 89, 23);
            contentPane.add(btnFinish);

            JButton btnAddChoice = new JButton("Add choice");
            btnAddChoice.setBounds(236, 228, 89, 23);
            contentPane.add(btnAddChoice);

            JButton btnAddQuestion = new JButton("Add question");
            btnAddQuestion.setBounds(136, 228, 89, 23);
            contentPane.add(btnAddQuestion);

        }
        private class SwingAction extends AbstractAction {
            public SwingAction() {
                putValue(NAME, "");
                putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Some short description");
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

- Having multiple JFrame instances in one application is bad usability
- Consider using something like a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead.

Comment: Why was my answer edited to point to some other discussion on SO? I was not even aware of that particular question when I posted my reply. I can understand editing for formatting or linking to javadocs but changing it to a URL to point to someone else's answer is not correct. Please undo the false linking

Comment: OK never mind. I edited it out myself. If you want to provide additional information/references, by all means, please do so. Just do NOT provide them in my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Modify like this-

```
JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        second_add second = new second_add();   
        setVisible(false); // Hide current frame
        second.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution would to set the first frame's visibility to false and the second frames visibility to true in your buttonclick action. (see Sajal Dutta's answer)

But to have a consistent behaviour even for more than 2 frames, let each frame be stored in a HashTable in your main class (class holding the `main` method and **not** extending JFrame) with the ID being the order of the frame (first frame D 1, second: ID 2, etc.).

Then create a static method

```
public void switchFrame(JFrame originatingFrame, int NextFrame){
    originatingFrame.this.setVisible(false);
    ((JFrame) myHashTable.get(NextFrame)).setVisible(true);
}
```

in your main class which can be called from each frame using

```
mainClass.switchFrame(this, IdOfFrameYouWantToGoTo);
```

that way you can also implement "Back"- and "Skip"-Buttons should you want to create something like a wizard.

**NOTE:** I did not test this code. This should just be seen as a general overview of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate to a frame by creating its object and using setVisible method to display it. If you want to do it on a button click, write it inside its event handler.

```
JFrame o = new JFrame();
o.setVisible(true);
dispose();        // This will close the current frame
```

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code will show to navigate from one page to another page in a menu format.

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Button;
    import java.awt.CardLayout;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.Panel;
    import java.awt.TextArea;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PipedInputStream;
    import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AddressBookDemo implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    ArrayList personsList;
    PersonDAO pDAO;
    Panel panel;
    JFrame appFrame;
    JLabel jlbName, jblPassword, jlbAddress;
    JPasswordField jPassword;
    JTextField jtfName, jtfAddress;
    JButton jbbSave, jbnClear, jbnExit, btnNext, button;
    String name, address, password;
    final int CARDS = 4;
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cl);
    CardLayout c2 = new CardLayout();
    JPanel cardPanel2 = new JPanel(c2);
    int currentlyShowing = 0;
    Thread errorThrower; 
    // int phone;
    // int recordNumber; // used to naviagate using >> and buttons
    Container cPane;
    Container cPane2;

    private JFrame frame;
    private TextArea textArea;
    private Thread reader;
    private Thread reader2;
    private boolean quit;

    private final PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream();
    private final PipedInputStream pin2 = new PipedInputStream();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new AddressBookDemo();
    }

    public AddressBookDemo() {
        name = "";
        password = "";
        address = "";
        // phone = -1; //Stores 0 to indicate no Phone Number
        // recordNumber = -1;
        createGUI();
        personsList = new ArrayList();
        // creating PersonDAO object
        pDAO = new PersonDAO();
    }

    public void createGUI() {

        /* Create a frame, get its contentpane and set layout */
        appFrame = new JFrame("ManualDeploy ");
        cPane = appFrame.getContentPane();
        cPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
//      frame=new JFrame("Java Console");
        textArea=new TextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        Button button=new Button("clear");

         panel=new Panel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx01 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx01.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx01.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx01.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        panel.add(textArea,gridBagConstraintsx01);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx03 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx03.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx03.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gridBagConstraintsx03.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(button,gridBagConstraintsx03);
//      frame.add(panel);

//      frame.setVisible(true);     
//      cPane2 = frame.getContentPane();
//      cPane2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        button.addActionListener(this);

        try
        {
            PipedOutputStream pout=new PipedOutputStream(this.pin);
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(pout,true));  
        } 
        catch (java.io.IOException io)
        {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDOUT to this console\n"+io.getMessage());
        }
        catch (SecurityException se)
        {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDOUT to this console\n"+se.getMessage());
        } 

        try 
        {
            PipedOutputStream pout2=new PipedOutputStream(this.pin2);
            System.setErr(new PrintStream(pout2,true));
        } 
        catch (java.io.IOException io)
        {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDERR to this console\n"+io.getMessage());
        }
        catch (SecurityException se)
        {
            textArea.append("Couldn't redirect STDERR to this console\n"+se.getMessage());
        }       

        quit=false; // signals the Threads that they should exit

        // Starting two seperate threads to read from the PipedInputStreams             
        //
        reader=new Thread(this);
        reader.setDaemon(true); 
        reader.start(); 
        //
        reader2=new Thread(this);   
        reader2.setDaemon(true);    
        reader2.start();

        // testing part
        // you may omit this part for your application
        // 
        System.out.println("Hello World 2");
        System.out.println("All fonts available to Graphic2D:\n");
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        String[] fontNames=ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        for(int n=0;n<fontNames.length;n++)  System.out.println(fontNames[n]);      
        // Testing part: simple an error thrown anywhere in this JVM will be printed on the Console
        // We do it with a seperate Thread becasue we don't wan't to break a Thread used by the Console.
        System.out.println("\nLets throw an error on this console");    
        errorThrower=new Thread(this);
        errorThrower.setDaemon(true);
        errorThrower.start();



        arrangeComponents();
        // arrangeComponents2();
        final int CARDS = 2;
        final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cl);
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("M");
        for (int x = 0; x < CARDS; x++) {
            final int SELECTION = x;
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();
            if (x == 0) {
                jp.add(cPane);
            } else if (x == 1) {
                 jp.add(panel);
            } else if (x == 2)
                jp.add(new JButton("Panel 2"));
            else
                jp.add(new JComboBox(new String[] { "Panel 3" }));
            cardPanel.add("" + SELECTION, jp);
            JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Show Panel " + x);
            menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    currentlyShowing = SELECTION;
                    cl.show(cardPanel, "" + SELECTION);
                }
            });
            menu.add(menuItem);
        }
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(menu);

        btnNext = new JButton("Next >>");

        JButton btnPrev = new JButton("<< Previous");
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        p.add(btnPrev);
        p.add(btnNext);
        btnNext.setVisible(false);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(cardPanel);
        f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        f.setVisible(true);
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (currentlyShowing < CARDS - 1) {
                    cl.next(cardPanel);
                    currentlyShowing++;
                }
            }
        });
        btnPrev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (currentlyShowing > 0) {
                    cl.previous(cardPanel);
                    currentlyShowing--;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void arrangeComponents() {
        jlbName = new JLabel("Username");
        jblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
        jlbAddress = new JLabel("Sftpserver");
        jtfName = new JTextField(20);
        jPassword = new JPasswordField(20);
        jtfAddress = new JTextField(20);
        jbbSave = new JButton("move sftp");
        jbnClear = new JButton("Clear");
        jbnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        /* add all initialized components to the container */
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx01 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx01.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx01.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx01.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(jlbName, gridBagConstraintsx01);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx02 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx02.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraintsx02.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gridBagConstraintsx02.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx02.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraintsx02.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        cPane.add(jtfName, gridBagConstraintsx02);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx03 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx03.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx03.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gridBagConstraintsx03.gridy = 1;
        cPane.add(jblPassword, gridBagConstraintsx03);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx04 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx04.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraintsx04.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gridBagConstraintsx04.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraintsx04.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraintsx04.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        cPane.add(jPassword, gridBagConstraintsx04);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx05 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx05.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx05.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gridBagConstraintsx05.gridy = 2;
        cPane.add(jlbAddress, gridBagConstraintsx05);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx06 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx06.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraintsx06.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraintsx06.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gridBagConstraintsx06.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraintsx06.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        cPane.add(jtfAddress, gridBagConstraintsx06);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx09 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx09.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraintsx09.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraintsx09.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(jbbSave, gridBagConstraintsx09);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx10 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx10.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraintsx10.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraintsx10.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(jbnClear, gridBagConstraintsx10);
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsx11 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraintsx11.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraintsx11.gridy = 4;
        gridBagConstraintsx11.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        cPane.add(jbnExit, gridBagConstraintsx11);
        jbbSave.addActionListener(this);
        // jbnDelete.addActionListener(this);
        jbnClear.addActionListener(this);
        jbnExit.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("inside button123");
        if (e.getSource() == jbbSave) {
            savePerson();
        } else if (e.getSource() == jbnClear) {
            clear();
        } else if (e.getSource() == jbnExit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == button)
        {
            System.out.println("inside button");
            textArea.setText(" ");
        }
    }

    // Save the Person into the Address Book
    public void savePerson() {
        name = jtfName.getText();
        password = jPassword.getText();
        address = jtfAddress.getText();
        if (name.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter password",
                    "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else if (password != null && password.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter password",
                    "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        else {
            btnNext.setVisible(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Person Saved");
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        jtfName.setText("");
        jPassword.setText("");
        jtfAddress.setText("");
        personsList.clear();
    }

    public synchronized void run()
    {
        try
        {           
            while (Thread.currentThread()==reader)
            {
                try { this.wait(100);}catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
                if (pin.available()!=0)
                {
                    String input=this.readLine(pin);
                    textArea.append(input);
                }
                if (quit) return;
            }

            while (Thread.currentThread()==reader2)
            {
                try { this.wait(100);}catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
                if (pin2.available()!=0)
                {
                    String input=this.readLine(pin2);
                    textArea.append(input);
                }
                if (quit) return;
            }           
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            textArea.append("\nConsole reports an Internal error.");
            textArea.append("The error is: "+e);            
        }

        // just for testing (Throw a Nullpointer after 1 second)
//      if (Thread.currentThread()==errorThrower)
//      {
//          try { this.wait(1000); }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
//          throw new NullPointerException("Application test: throwing an NullPointerException It should arrive at the console");
//      }

    }

    public synchronized String readLine(PipedInputStream in) throws IOException
    {
        String input="";
        do
        {
            int available=in.available();
            if (available==0) break;
            byte b[]=new byte[available];
            in.read(b);
            input=input+new String(b,0,b.length);                                                       
        }while( !input.endsWith("\n") &&  !input.endsWith("\r\n") && !quit);
        return input;
    }   
    public synchronized void windowClosed(WindowEvent evt)
    {
        quit=true;
        this.notifyAll(); // stop all threads
        try { reader.join(1000);pin.close();   } catch (Exception e){}      
        try { reader2.join(1000);pin2.close(); } catch (Exception e){}
        System.exit(0);
    }       



}
```